# Redefine core function in another namespace

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

Is it possible to redefine a core PHP function in another namespace, like function echo?

Something like:

```
namespace test;
function echo($yo) {
  \echo('--' . $yo);
}
echo 'lol';
```

I am pretty new with understanding namespace and I would like to know how far we can use it.

Comment: `echo` isn't actually a function, it is a language construct.  See: http://php.net/echo  Because of this, you cannot name a function `echo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this for `echo`, because it's not actually a function.  `echo` is a "language construct" and a reserved word.  You cannot name a function `echo`.

For built-in functions (that are actually functions) however, what you have is right.  For example:

```
namespace test;
function print_r($yo) {
  \print_r('--' . $yo);
}
print_r('lol');
```

Comment: It would have been too great :-)